# How to catch 500 server error with selenium webdriver during a test in a webpage?

Tags: selenium

i have a java code with selenium webdriver to test the presence of some element in a webpage.
The test passed each time it found elements but sometime when i have a 500 server error message on the top of the webpage, the test passes successfully.
How can i fetch this server error message in my test.
What is the web element of this error message?

Any help
Thank you

Comment: Another possibility is have the application dump out errors to the console -> Selenium will then give you access to those logs. You just then check to see if anything is in there.

Comment: IMHO - This shouldn't be a thing that you'll have to deal with (WebDriver). It's a bad idea (anti-pattern) to propagate such errors in the Presentation layer - just saying.

Answer (score 1):

I've done a check similar to this before in a Regression suite...

One thing you can do, is have a function that gets executed very frequently.  Something like this:

*(your tags are vague, so i will use pseudo-Java / WebDriver with jUnit)*

```java
import static org.junit.Assert.fail;

public void check500() {
    if (isPresent(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div#500.error"))))
        fail("500 page displayed! Failing test, and quitting.");
}
```

You will, of course, replace `"div#500.error"` with whatever element that IS unique within the 500 error page.  There's always going to be one.  Look around.

Comment: The best way is to export result test file from eclipse after the test, then you can find all exceptions occured during the test. But the above soltuions are good too but we should reproduce the exception then locate the element.

Comment: well that's completely different logic.  I was under the assumption (and the way your question was worded) that you were reaching a 500 page unintentionally and wanted to fail the script.  The logic you are saying then, is you are specifically testing the 500 page

Comment: i'm trying with Ant build file, in the report file there is not server error 500.every test passed successfully. i ave to try with Maven

Comment: Whether you are using Ivy or Maven is completely irrelevant.  Those are just build systems to run a test framework, jUnit, TestNG, etc.

Comment: So i will try your above code but i have to wait until the 500 server error message appears to find the element like div#500.error

Answer (score 0):

I do this to catch my errors present on a webpage

```java
try {

    List<WebElement> errors = m_driver
            .findElements(By.className(ALERT));

    //Print all the error messages displayed
    for (WebElement e : errors)
        log("MESSAGE : " + e.getText());

}

catch (Exception e) {
}
```

You can replace the By.className by anything else you want.